# SWT Text widget: how to insert own MenuItems into the default context menu?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

The default context menu for the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text class is quite a rich thing, packed with features that the user has come to depend on ...

[image: Default text context menu, Mac edition]

However, as soon as I assign my own context menu with Control.setMenu() all that richness goes away. Is there a means of inserting my own MenuItem object into this system-created menu .. can I have my cake **and** eat it?

Your clues are always most welcome.

M.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have MAC to try out my thoughts, but is `null` or some real `Menu` class instance returned from `Control.getMenu()` (default menu what are you talking about) before you set the new menu? If it's not null, try to get the items, if there is what are you lookin' for..

Comment: Interesting - I'd retag this as a mac / cocoa question to first figure out how to actually contribute to that menu and then second worry about how to make that happen from your java swt app.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the native menu from SWT. It is there, if there are no other menus set for the control. As you noticed, as soon as you set your own menu for the control, this new menu will completely replace the native menu.

As far as I can see, the behavior is common to all platforms.

Comment: If it's common, then there should be no problem for the SWT team to provide access to it, just similar to the application menu on OS X with SWT 3.7.